# Redirected folders to be allways on offline mode

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, folder-redirection, offline-files

I have made modifications to GPO users to have redirected folders like Desktop, my documents etc. I have redirected those to be on network share. Everything works fine.

I made edit to GPO to force everyone to work on offline mode and sync files only on bacground cycle. 
[see microsoft document about this.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968298(v=ws.11).aspx)

Ok. everyhing works on slow connected hosts (behind ADSL or 4G connection). files/folders are on Offline mode and syncked every 120 minutes or so. Problem is that fast connected host on local network are not forcred to be offline mode. could it be that the latency is faster than 1 ms?

Is there some way to force those redireted folder to be allways (sync only every 120 minutes) on Offline mode? And how to do that via GPO?

Server is 2008R2 entprice windows server and hosts are windows 10 hosts

Comment: sounds like a job for profile redirection

Comment: And that is?   We have been previously using roaming profiles before and are moving now to using redirected folders... Mobile users have problems with roaming profiles, mainly becouse profiles are easily quite big and nnetwork conection quite poor.

Comment: with roaming profiles asking a mobile user to download the entire profile over ADSL is a nightmare, switching back to local profiles with folder redirection and offline files is not much better (sorry to say). the best fit is Desktop as a service $$$$. In my opinion, desktops are disposable, only backup the users home directory, let them have local profiles, if they save everything to desktop (which they will) you'll be back to square one, logins slow way down etc.

Comment: if we think to leave profiles just to be local profiles, we need at least to back them up somehow. Any good, cheap solution to backup desktop, my document user folders easily?  Any scripted solution?